# Can I make a hybrid choropleth and marker chart in dc.leaflet.js?

Tags: maps, leaflet, data-visualization, dc.js, dc.leaflet.js

I need to make a crossfilterable data map that is a choropleth chart with markers as well.  The docs at https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js say:

> There are two charts currently implemented - markers and choropleth. They extend the base abstract leaflet chart.

I am not able to find any examples using dc.leaflet.js .  I have found an example that uses pure leaflet here: http://bl.ocks.org/awoodruff/3ce5d735126a56dfff94 . But I need to aggregate and filter the colors/markers.

Is this possible with dc.leaflet.js?

Comment: I'm sure you saw Yurukov's original example page [here](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.leaflet.js/). Assigning multiple dimensions to multiple layers is a great idea but it's not currently available through the API.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thank you for all your work with dc!  It is an immense help to our work.  Yes I did see those examples, and I did notice the hybrid chropleth-marker map examples missing, which caused some concern because if others much smarter than me haven't implemented it yet maybe it isn't feasible.  How difficult do you think it would be for someone to add that to the API?  I'm not asking you to do it, just if you are aware of any possible pitfalls.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult to implement the particular chart you're asking for, and one could probably paste together the two classes in an ad-hoc way with just a day's effort. What's more difficult is that dc.js doesn't have much framework for dealing with multiple series. I guess the simplest way to go forward in a reusable way would be to implement a composite leaflet chart like the dc [compositeChart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.compositeChart) - different interface and code but similar conceptually.

Comment: Probably still just a day of work. [I've filed an issue to track the idea.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js/issues/21)

Comment: Thank you for that!  But now you've identified another potential issue (mapping 2 sets of data into one chart) that I hadn't considered.